In a mixed model with intersubject and intrasubject variable what random effects should i put?
My master's thesis director wants to use a linear mixed model to analyze my data. My experiment has a task where participants click on a touch when a stimuli (a word) appears on screen. The dependent variable is the response time. Stimuli where chosen for their emotional valence: positive, neutral or negative. Every participant goes through every stimuli. They also have a physical task to accomplish during the clicking task. Half of the participants have Task A and half have Task B, which makes it an inter-subject variable. In the random effects, in addition to the participants, I want to put the stimulus since there is a random variability among them, like theirs length etc. But I don't know how to write that down in R. I don't know if it's already taken account in the model by the fixed effects, but I want the model to only take as a random effect of the stimulus the part that is not explained by the emotional valence.
My current model is as follows:
model <- lmer(response_time ~ emotional_valence *  experimental_condition + (1 | stimulus) + (1|participant), data = data).


Your syntax here is correct. This models crossed random effects between subjects and stimuli (which is good because all subjects are subject to all stimuli here). You might also be able to sneak emotional valence in as a random slope like so:
model <- lmer(response_time ~ emotional_valence *  experimental_condition + (1 | stimulus) + (1 + emotional_valence | participant), data = data)

This is because all the subjects, due to being exposed to various stimuli, have multiple observations of emotional valence by response time within their clusters. I wouldn't bother throwing experimental condition in as a random slope given it only has two levels.
This is based on the assumption that emotional valence has enough meaningful random effect variance to estimate this model. If this specification makes the model crash (e.g. creates a singular fit), it is best to keep the one you already have.
I am also assuming that you actually want valence to be coded in a more continuous manner. Typically in psycholinguistics, valence is continuous, as shown here from Statistics for Linguists:


Thank you ! It really helped me !

No problem. Btw this paper does a great job of detailing what crossed random effects models do if you are interested. It uses an example which should be related to yours since you seem to also be using this for psycholinguistics.

Is emotional valence measured as a continuous or categorical predictor? OP mentions it having three levels. We can't see the output of the model, but unless the variable is identified as a factor, they will get only one coefficient for the fixed effect and one variance (plus covariance) for the random effect. I don't think that makes sense for a variable such as this unless I am not understanding how valence is measured.

Typically valence is treated as continuous  in psycholinguistics. I have edited the answer to clarify this point.

Why not a random slope due to only having two levels?

Hmm you can certainly enter a two-level dummy-coded variable in as a random slope, but from my own experience this tends to be trickier to get the model to converge. One can enter it into the model and try it, if there is reason to believe there is enough random effect variance for it to work.
